# pandas Pivot table error calculation of new column if column not present

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, crosstab

I am newbee to python
I am trying pivot table function in pandas, while doing that

```
y["Out bin"]=y["30-40 Mins"]+y["40-50 Mins"]
```

all the columns ["30-40 Mins"] and["40-50 Mins"] are calculated fields
but doing so if category y["40-50 Mins"] is not present in raw data (derived column) then it gives key error for the same , I know this is bcz category is not present in calculated fields

is their any way i can solve this issue as if the column is not present it can ommit the same and add column in pivot table without any error

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) for get columns names if exist and then `sum`:

```
vals = ['30-40 Mins', '40-50 Mins']
y["Out bin"] = y[y.columns.intersection(vals)].sum(axis=1)
```